# Swift 2.1 ios 9 google maps can t load image with custom markerInfoWindow

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, swift2, gmsmapview

i'm trying to load image in custom markerInfoWindow and it don't work 
what's missing all others are working fine like RestName and DiscText
i tried with 3 method 
1- Normal Load image from NSRL but it crashed 
2- load with  asynchronously with image cache nothing happen
3- using  KFSwiftImageLoader lib also nothing happen

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {

 //   var imageRest : UIImage!
    if  let infoWindow :CustomInfoRest = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomInfo", owner: self.view, options: nil).first! as? CustomInfoRest {



         rest = marker.userData as! Restaurant


        infoWindow.DescText.text = rest.description
        infoWindow.RestNameText.text = rest.name
        RestLocation = CLLocation(latitude: rest.latitude, longitude: rest.longitude)


        infoWindow.RatingView.rating = Double(rest.rate)!
        infoWindow.RatingView.settings.updateOnTouch = false

        infoWindow.RatingView.settings.fillMode = .Precise


        let distanceBetween: CLLocationDistance =
        RestLocation.distanceFromLocation(UserLocation) / 1000
        let distanceInMile = distanceBetween / 1.60934

        infoWindow.lan.text = String(format: "%.2f Miles", distanceInMile)


  /*

        let url = rest.image
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
      infoWindow.Restimage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

*/

```
        // Image loading.
        infoWindow.imageUrl = rest.image
        // For recycled cells' late image loads.
        if let image = rest.image.cachedImage {
            // Cached: set immediately.

            infoWindow.Restimage.image = image
            infoWindow.Restimage.alpha = 1

        } else {
            // Not cached, so load then fade it in.
           infoWindow.Restimage.alpha = 0
            rest.image.fetchImage { image in
                // Check the cell hasn't recycled while loading.
                if infoWindow.imageUrl == self.rest.image {


                     infoWindow.Restimage.image = image
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
                     infoWindow.Restimage.alpha = 1


                    }
                }
            }
        }






         /*
        infoWindow.Restimage.loadImageFromURLString(String(self.rest.image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "LOGO")) {
            (finished, error) in
            print(error)
            print(finished)

        }
        */

         infoWindow.RestNameText.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        infoWindow.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        infoWindow.frame = CGRectMake(infoWindow.frame.minX,infoWindow.frame.minY-100,infoWindow.frame.width,infoWindow.frame.height)
     //   infoWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
      // infoWindow.Restimage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


        return infoWindow
    } else {
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as well. Has a resolution been found?